# A Samsung Galaxy SII giveaway... with a twist (UPDATED x2)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**Update x2:** See [the official contest meta post](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/667/samsung-galaxy-sii-twitter-se-giveaway-official-post).

**Update:** *This contest will now be taking place next week (10.17-10.21). Also, instead of leaving an Answer, contestants will only have to gain 5 points across the Android site during the contest period to increase their chances of winning **3x**. Eligible participants will be calculated on the back-end by the Community & CHAOS teams and a winner will be randomly generated and announced at the end of the contest period. Stay tuned for the official contest post, published Monday.*

.....

We have a Galaxy SII to giveaway via Twitter tomorrow (Wednesday 10/12). RT a message announced tomorrow morning, and your name will be entered into a random drawing.

This is an outreach initiative, and the main purpose is to use this goodie to spread the word on Android.SE. But I want to make sure that established Stack Exchange users have a leg up on the competition here. Also, I want to try something new.

With that in mind, I've proposed contestants can double (or triple - I'm undecided here) their chances by leaving an "Answer" in the official contest meta post. Leaving an answer in meta requires 5 rep points.

In a brief chat yesterday, @MatthewRead cleared using a meta Answer as contest platform in this instance. Depending on how it turns out, this may be a one and done contest model.

Any thoughts? Should an answer 2x or 3x a participant's chances? We want established users to be rewarded. Also, we want newbies to participate on the site (but not perversely). Yet we don't want to strongly discourage RT-ing the tweet as making this a Twitter contest was a precondition to receiving the phone.

Lemme know your thoughts!

Comment: Is this global or limited to certain regions?

Comment: @onik - the phone is SIM-locked to T-Mobile US only. However the contest will be worldwide.

Comment: Where is the official meta post? Is this it?

Comment: What's the point of a world wide competition for a T-Mobile locked phone?

Comment: Nick, Android phones are easily unlocked :D

Answer (score 5):

Does the five points need to come from site participation or does the 101 points you get from linking to another exchange count?

Methinks participation should be required.

Comment: This is a good question. We'll make participation required. I'll be sure to mention this when the official meta post is published Monday.

Answer (score 2):

Due to limited space, contest tweets normally look something like this:

> RT for a chance to win a Galaxy S II from android.stackexchange.com! <Open worldwide/US-only/etc.> Full details: link.to/details

I would suspect that most people won't look at the details if the quote includes the crucial info (who can enter).  That *should* be enough to "hide" the extra entries (avoiding attracting spammers to the site or discouraging people who think they can't win with only 1 entry).

Couple that with a featured post here or a system message, and I think the contest should work well.  And my vote is for a post here to increase one's chances by 3x :P

Answer (score 2):

How will you link Twitter accounts with the persons stack exchange account? Will we have to register in some way?

Comment: Wanted to ask the same.. There's no separate place to put twitterid in account settings.

Comment: Maybe it'll be posted as a question on the site and we can use the tweet link feature? That'll probably register in the SO database that we've tweeted it. #guess

Comment: @BernhardHofmann - You'll simply have to add your twitter account to one of any of the fields in your SE profile. I will clarify the instructions when the official meta post is published Monday.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Looking forward to a chance to win that great phone. (This comment written on my HTC WildFire.)

Answer (score 1):

I think there could be some way to link tweet-driven contest entries directly to your twitter and stack-exchange account by using a hash tag that would register the tweeter for the contest. Wouldn't that also help with trending?

Answer (score 0):

Umm - if everyone gets a 2x or 3x, you'll have the same probability of winning. It doesn't matter. You could do a 10x probability. Everything still remains the same.

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Lazy people will simply retweet rather than participate, so there is a scale.

Comment: There's an SII at stake my friend! And 5 points = 2x (or 3x) the chances.