# Samsung Galaxy SII Twitter + SE Giveaway (UPDATE: We Have A Winner!)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

---- *This contest is now closed* ----

You got [the heads up](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/a-samsung-galaxy-sii-giveaway-with-a-twist-updated). Now it's time to participate.

**The prize:** A T-Mobile US SIM-locked Samsung Galaxy SII
[image]

**The rules:**

- Include your Twitter handle anywhere in your Android.StackExchange
  profile.
- Retweet [THIS](http://twitter.com/#!/StackHQ/status/125935452384538624) (or [the Tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/124273939714277378) previously posted by Jeff) to enter the
  contest.
- Earn 5 points across the Android site (excluding points earned from
  linking SE accounts) from now until Friday, 3pm EST to increase your chances of winning **3-fold**.

**The terms:**

- Anyone, anywhere is eligible.
- A winner will be chosen at random and announced Monday, October 24.

Good luck!

Comment: How ironic, without intending to, I downloaded the manual for this phone to answer a question that earned me the rep to get my 3-fold chance of winning. Roll on Monday. Fingers crossed!

Comment: When and where will the winner be announced?

Comment: @AlEverett - The results will be up later today (maybe 3pm EST) in a meta post.

Comment: @SamTheBrandΨ we're waiting... ;)

Comment: Ah good, it's Monday 24th. So you'll be needing my address to post the phone to won't you? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations to **Mike Stride** ([@stridermike](http://twitter.com/#!/stridermike)) of Southport, UK, who was one of 272 people to enter by RT-ing the [@STackHQ contest announcement](http://twitter.com/#!/StackHQ/status/125935452384538624). Stride did not triple his chances of winning by earning 5 rep on the Android site. If he didn't have Android questions before, the UK citizen may come up with a few as he tries to get his brand new US-locked Samsung Galaxy SII up and running!

Stay tuned for another Android contest in the coming weeks.

Comment: Does Mike Stride have an account? A Google search doesn't reveal any instance of "stridermike" on this site except for this post

Comment: @SamTheBrand where there any winners announced for the previous competition? Think I remember seeing some new names during that week.

Comment: @KyleCronin - As far as I know, Mike Stride does not have an account. But that was never a prerequisite of the contest.

Comment: @SamTheBrandΨ isn't that first under 'The Rules'?

Comment: @KyleCronin - Yikes. You're right. From what I wrote, it may be interpreted that owning a SE profile is a prerequisite. I should have been more clear, and in future contests I will be.

Comment: @SamTheBrandΨ FWIW, I think that having an account definitely *should* be a prerequisite to win. The tweet should probably also mention that the link has the rules, and not simply a way to triple your chances

Comment: I WAS ROBBED!!! Oh and congrats @stridermike ;)

Comment: Congrats Mike. I expect to see some questions (and answers) about your SGS2.